# Link in iframe causing parent page to jump to top

Tags: iframe

I have a long html page. At the bottom is an iframe with a long list of links. The links open new pages in the iframe.

When links are clicked inside the iframe, the parent page (as expected) jumps to the top and I have to scroll way back down to get back to the iframe and its newly loaded page.

Here's one hurdle. The iframe contents is hosted on another server outside my control. The admins there have graciously added a call to a js file hosted on our server from the iframe src, but I still can't crack this.

Do I need to calculate the distance of each link from its window top and also the iframe's distance from it's window top and do a bunch of math and then scroll back to that position after the new page loads?

Suggestions?

Comment: Did they do something else? I tried to replicate the issue and it is not jumping to the top on either FF or Chrome.

Comment: show your code,because this behaviour  should not happen.

Comment: I'm realizing this now. I recreated the scenario using two servers I control and could not reproduce this problem.